# How can I render emoji in my React app (using Webpack)?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, emoji

I've tried using emojis in my React components in a few different ways (i.e. ✨, {'\u2728'}, and a few component libraries). Every way works with my *dev* build of the code and fails with my *prod* build of the same code.

The prod build outputs the Unicode value of the emoji despite the method I use in the code, so I think it has something to do with my Webpack config, but I cannot find any solution on the web.

**Dev output**

[image]

**Prod output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While making sure I had all the details to ask my question, I did some digging on something I hadn't looked up before and found my answer.

My searching led me to this GitHub issue ([link](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2488)) where someone was having this issue using create-react-app. Ultimately, the issue was an underlying issue with UglifyJS which required an `ascii_only` argument to be passed in that step.

I checked out the current version of create-react-app's Webpack config and added the relevant bits to my project and it fixed my solution. Here's the source I used ([link](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js#L263)).

The minimum config needed looks like:

```
    optimization: {
      minimize: isEnvProduction,
      minimizer: [
        new TerserPlugin({
          terserOptions: {
            output: {
              // Turned on because emoji and regex is not minified properly using default
              // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2488
              ascii_only: true,
            },
          },
        }),
      ],
    },
```